# How to map a house layout, room by room to be used for simple room to room navigation by a robot?

Tags: algorithm, arduino, geolocation, computer-vision, robotics

I am planning on a robot, basically an Arduino coupled with a webcam and RC car to navigate from a point in the house to another using a map of the house layout made possibly by a webcam tour of the place.

It should receive a command to where it should go based on input from my smartphone or PC. Each room will have an ID code which the robot should use to determine the travel path.

Also, it should be able to go to the room where I am based on locating me using Bluetooth or Wifi.

Sensors: Proximity sensors and light sensors

I live in the house, so that is not an issue.
Any ideas on where I can start?

Comment: What about temporary obstacles, like chairs? Should it detect them? If so, how? Are the doors always open?

Comment: the simpliest, but not very tolerate, is to use IBeacon proximity sensors.

Comment: For now, no obstacle detection. I am a beginner so want to get the bare essentials working. In future, I will port this to a drone which will include obstacle detection.

Answer (score 0):

I participated in a similar project, it will be more difficult than you think now.

We used bluetooth beacons. Fix their positions, then you can measure the signal strength with the robot. If you know the positions of the beacon (they are fix), then you can calculate where is the robot actually. But they are very inaccurate, and takes a couple of seconds to scan all the beacons.

If you want to navigate through your house, I think the easiest way that you plant the beacons, go around in the house with the robot and measure the signals (the more the better). This way you can create a discrete layout of your house. In my opinion the easiest way to store the map if you represent the layout as a graph. The nodes are the discrete points you measured, and there exists an edge between two nodes if the robot can travel between them in "one step". This way you can represent temporary obstacles too, for example delete an edge. And the robot can easily determine which way to go, just use Dijsktra's algorithm.